# Multiclass classification metrics : average probability

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multi-class, metric

I'm looking for a metric to evaluate my classification model. I have 3 differents class (0,1,2).
And I want to get the average probability of the good label. For example, if my ml model get me those probas :
[[0.5, 0.25, 0.25],
[0.1, 0.8, 0.1],
[0.7, 0.2, 0.1]]
And the true labels are [0,1,0], then the evaluation result should be (0.5+0.8+0.7)/3 = 0.66.

Does this metric has a name ?

Comment: Hi Yoann, was your question answered? If so, could you please accept the correct answer with the checkmark beside it? Otherwise, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 4):

Yup! It has a name, and it makes sense to care about. It's called the **expected accuracy**—and alternatively, one minus the expected error rate.

The idea is that you pretend to pick a class *randomly* from the posterior distribution instead of picking the most probable class. (That is—**stochastic decoding** instead of MAP decoding.) If the probability of the correct class is 0.8, you'll still pick this 80% of the time, so you get 80% credit.